# Python: Having Trouble Connecting to Postgresql DB

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I have been using the following lines of code for the longest time, without any hitch, but today it seems to have produced the following error and I cannot figure out why. The strange thing is that I have other scripts that use the same code and they all seem to work...

```
import pandas as pd
import psycopg2
link_conn_string = "host='<host>'  dbname='<db>'  user='<user>'  password='<pass>'"
conn = psycopg2.connect(link_conn_string)
df = pd.read_sql("SELECT * FROM link._link_bank_report_lms_loan_application", link_conn_string)
```

Error Message:

```
    "Could not parse rfc1738 URL from string '%s'" % name)
sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: Could not parse rfc1738 URL from string 'host='<host>'  dbname='<db>'  user='<user>'  password='<pass>''
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean? Could you please clarify?

Comment: It's a url address like "blahblahblah.com"

Comment: That's because I changed the traceback error as I want to protect the privacy of the credentials

Comment: Apologies - wasn't sure what you were referring to. Hence why I asked you to clarify.

Comment: Well it's going to be very difficult for people to guess why Psycopg can't parse a URI you aren't showing.

Comment: Duly noted for next time.

Comment: Why do you pass `link_conn_string` to `pd.read_sql()` rather than the connection `conn` that you created on the previous line?  (I have no experience with `psycopg2`, `pandas`, or `sqlalchemy`, but that seems odd to me.)

Comment: Excellent catch! Thanks Steven.

Comment: Was that the root of your problem?

Comment: It most certainly was! Thanks again. I'm so careless sometimes.

Answer (score 2):

change `link_conn_string` to be like [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/libpq-connect.html#LIBPQ-CONNSTRING):

```
postgresql://[user[:password]@][netloc][:port][/dbname][?param1=value1&...]
```

Eg:

```
>>> import psycopg2
>>> cs = 'postgresql://vao@localhost:5432/t'
>>> c = psycopg2.connect(cs)
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.read_sql("SELECT now()",c)
>>> print df;
                               now
0 2017-02-27 21:58:27.520372+00:00
```

Answer (score -1):

Your connection string is wrong.

You should remove the line where you assign a string to "link_conn_string" variable and replace the next line with something like this (remember to replace **localhost**, **postgres** and **secret** with the name of the machine where postgresql is running, the **user** and **password** required to make that connection):

```
conn = psycopg2.connect(dbname="localhost", user="postgres", password="secret")
```

Also, you can check if the database is working with "psql" command, from the terminal, type (again, remember to change user and database):

```
psql -U postgresql database
```

Comment: I suspect that's a typo in [the docs](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/module.html), because there's an `=` missing for keyword arguments. Also they do say that a string similar to the OP's is a valid alternative.